# recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

Given this method call:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fib(3));
}

private static int fib(int i) {
     System.out.println("Into fib with i = " + i);

    if (i < 2) {
        System.out.println("We got here");
        return i;
    }
    return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2); 
}

 }
```

I expected:

```
* fib(i-1) to return 2
* fib(i-2) to return 1
* return 2 + 1 to return 3
```

Result:

```
2
```

This is the output of console:

```
Into fib with i = 3
Into fib with i = 2
Into fib with i = 1
We got here
Into fib with i = 0
We got here
```

I understand everything up to this part:

```
Into fib with i = 0
```

When could have i ever been 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fib(3)` calls `fib(2)`.  When you call `fib(2)`, it will call `fib(i-1)` and `fib(i-2)`, that is, `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`.

Comment: to fix it, just replace the statement "return i" with "return 1"

Comment: Well this function reproduces the fibonacci formula, which starts with 0, so it first returns 0. But this does answer my question.